# Passing a method as parameter from a parent LWC to a chil LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, parameters, method

Hello,

I develop on an existing LWC and there is something I don't understand.
There are 2 custom LWC and the parent LWC calls the child LWC by passing a method (from him) as a parameter the child LWC.

This is the call:

```
<c-child-component
    onrefreshsalesassociates={handleRefreshSalesAssociates}
```

> 

"handleRefreshSalesAssociates" is a method in the parent LWC but not in the child LWC, it is not a variable.

My question is what is "onrefreshsalesassociates"?
I can't find anything in the parent LWC and in the child LWC.

Do you know what it is and how it is used please (or maybe a keyword to give me the opportunity to search on the internet)?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look for `refreshsalesassociates` (without the "on") in your child LWC, then at [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch) or [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers).

Comment: The best practice is to fire an event from the child and handle that in the parent, instead of passing down the method. What is your use case, and what is the need for sending the handler from parent to child?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a component's markup, the `on` prefix is reserved for [event handlers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_handling) (e.g. you can't declare a variable called `onsuccess`). Inside the component that is [dispatching the event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch), you'll find code similar to the following:

```
const event = new CustomEvent("refreshsalesassociates");
this.template.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Events are the standard way for a child to communicate with its parent. To pass data from a parent to a child, it is typical to use [public properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reactivity_public).

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class MyComponentName extends LightningElement {
  @api myProperty;
}
```

Which is then set by a property in kebab-case, as specified in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/js_props_names).

```
<c-my-component-name my-property={someParentVariable}>
</c-my-component-name>
```